# Ubuntu 16.04 IRQ kernel panic at shutdown on Alienware R7 desktop

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, kernel, shutdown

I freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 that was preinstalled on the PC and updated the Nvidia graphics drivers. Somehow I can't shutdown, and get IRQ interruptions, Ubuntu gets stuck at a black screen and then I can do nothing except hold down the power button to shutdown the computer.

[image: error message screenshot]

When I boot Ubuntu, the screen will flash black before rendering the desktop.

I tried to update grub: `ACHI=force` which didn't help. I suspect it is an issue with some drivers, but I'm not sure what causes it. I tried to determine which GPU is active, and I tested:

```
glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer*"
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1080/PCIe/SSE2
```

Nvidia X Server Settings application shows that it is using Nvidia driver version 384.90.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `BIOS` settings.

1. Switch off `Secure boot`.
2. Enable `Legacy` boot mode.
3. `Raid` option must be switch on.

In my case I use restart for poweroff ^_^.

With default poweroff method I always get kernel panic.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the Ubuntu 16.04LTS along with Window 10 on Alienware R7 desktop and faced the same problem. It seems like Kernel is incompatible. 
 
 
Here are the steps I have done after restarting the computer to figure out the problem.
 
 
1. In the grub menu, choose "Advanced options for ubuntu", then choose previous kernel version. Now you are able to login.
 
 
2. run the terminal and upgrade by

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then you won't suffer kernel panic when shutdown

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the system did not solve my problem, I solved it editing the file */etc/default/grub* and adding the kernel option `noapic`, this way:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet noapic splash"
```

After that you should also launch the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now my system shutdown without any problem