# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Alienware Aurora R7, Kernel panic on shutdown

Tags: kernel, shutdown, alienware

I just installed 16.04 LTS on my new desktop, Dell Alienware Aurora R7, with i7-8700K, 32GB RAM, SSD(SM961 NVMe SSD) and 1080TI.

So far, everything works ok except I get a kernel panic when I try to shutdown (reboot works ok).

[image: kernel panic screen capture]

How can I avoid that?

Comment: What kernel are you running (use `uname -a` to determine)? You may want to move to a different kernel. That said, since the issue is on shutdown, I wouldn't be too concerned (that's just me).

Comment: `4.13.0-36-generic #40~16.04.1-Ubuntu`.

Comment: Have you tried to disable(blacklist) i2c module noted in this link:
http://helloworldproject.blogspot.com/2016/11/installing-ubuntu-1610-on-alienware.html

Comment: I faced the same issue myself and found a solution. See my answer here for the instructions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446913/52937

Comment: This answer will help you https://askubuntu.com/a/1047057/486406

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking into this due to the fact that I might get the same system.

There was a previous question for this situation for which an answer mentioned choosing a previous kernel version. That might solve it:
[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS IRQ kernel panic at shutdown - Alienware R7 desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986895/ubuntu-16-04-lts-irq-kernel-panic-at-shutdown-alienware-r7-desktop/994993)

BTW did you try the system with the latest non-LTS version of Ubuntu? That could also work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

On my Dell Alienware 17R3 with Samsung Pro 960 NVMe SSD I had a problem suspending/resuming lockup fixed by editing `/etc/default/grub` and adding the parameter `acpiphp.disable=1` to the line containing:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Afterwards it looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpiphp.disable=1"
```

Save the file. Next update `/boot/grub.cfg` and generate a new `initrd.img` with the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Finally reboot and test.

---

I don't have the PM961, but rather the 960 Pro so haven't experienced your issue. If none of the other answers or comments help one last thing you could try is:

```
nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500
```

parameter in `/etc/default/grub` LINUX kernel argument list. I just found this in [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drive/NVMe). There are other steps you may wish to investigate in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I have an **Alienware Aurora R7/0VDT73, BIOS 1.0.11**.  The system crashed on shutdown because of IRQ issues on a built-in-module (i2c-designware-core).

I solved this by editing the file **/etc/default/grub** and adding the kernel option **noapic**, to this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet noapic splash"
```

After that you should also launch the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now my system shuts down without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this issue!

Add initcall_blacklist=dw_i2c_init_driver to the kernel command line. This works for me on kernel 4.15.0+.

For anyone else who'll find this answer. You can do it by editing /etc/default/grub:

Run in the terminal: sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub.

(if you don't have gedit installed use your favorite text editor or
"sudo apt install gedit" without quotes)

Append blacklist string to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet initcall_blacklist=dw_i2c_init_driver".

Save the file, close the editor.

Run in the terminal: sudo update-grub.

Reboot and test!

Credit goes to this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423797/how-do-i-disable-i2c-designware-support-when-its-not-built-as-a-module/446913#446913

These are my specs for this rig.
Alienware Aurora R5
Nvidia GTX 1070/8GBvram 
8GB ram
i7 Intel core processor(8core)"Skylake"

Comment: It seems that this is the actual answer " How I solved this issue was installing Manjaro and using their built in kernel installer,and switched to a "Real Time" kernel. "  I suggest editing your answer to make this stand out more.